# Android run app secretly in background

Tags: android

I have a client that needs a spy app that will run in the background - take received messages, sent messages, gps location etc. Can I start a service without user interface of Activity? As I understand, I need a service and receiver, I also need to call the receiver on let's say battery low, battery ok - some very often triggered intents. How can I test this on emulator?

For now this is what I have

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(intent.getAction() != null)
    {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) ||
            intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT))
        {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
        }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}
    }

for receiver and

```
public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
Toast.makeText(this,"Service created ...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed ...",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

}

for service .
I put this in my manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.services"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="4" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <service android:name=".MyService"></service>
    <receiver  android:name=".MyReceiver"></receiver>
</application>
```

Am I on a good way?

Comment: This sounds like a spy app. Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this answer:

**It is possible pre Android 3.0**

Upto Android 2.3, apps can register broadcast receivers for any event, and they will be launched when that even occurs. This can be Boot Complete, Screen On/Off, anything basically.

**It is not possible on 3.0 and above**

3.0 introduced a very helpful condition to receiving event broadcasts. Your app *must* have been launched *at least* once before it will receive events. If the user installs your app, but never opens it, then you will not receive any broadcasts even if you have receivers defined for them in your app.

Also, keep in mind that your app can be force stopped by the user or the system itself at any point of time. Morever, users running ICS and above have the option to Disable apps, which ensures that they will never run at all unless reenabled manually. You cannot control either of these situations.

The only way to have a foolproof spy app is to bake it into the ROM on the device, which isn't very viable when targetting more than a few devices.

Comment: Ok , the person will launch it once after installing it .This first time I could have a user interface but later on it must run in the background from time to time ...How can I test this, can I do it on emulator . Is my code fine I added to the manifest  <receiver  android:name=".MyReceiver">
              <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
   </intent-filter>
            
        </receiver>

Comment: Your code is correct, but you need an Activity to show for the first launch. Beyond that, you should really be testing this on a device.

Comment: Where can I see on my phone that the service is running . I added an Activity with button to start the service and one to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can start `Service` without User interaction. But surelly you need something to trigger your code "where you start the service" right?

For this I can suggest you to have one more BroadcastReceiver with very frequent intent, Like `Phone_state_change`,`"Incoming_mesage"` `Time_tick`. so when it happens you get your onReceive method called, and you can start your service from there, You need to check if service is not already running right?

I will suggest you to define a `sticky` `BroadcastReceiver`. it gets its `onReceive` called immediatly after registering it, so you `start` your `service` from here too.

Thats what i did, hope it works for you. Let me know the output.

Happy coding. :)